# Android layout weight (mix some objects with min size and some with max)

Tags: android, layout

I have a problem similar to [this question: Android Layout Weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986861/android-layout-weight)
but it do not seems to have the same answer...

Inside a tablerow, I would like to display TextViews and EditTexts, where the TextViews take minimal size, and EditTexts share the remaining size:

```
    'Size:[   edit1   ] x [   edit2   ] pixels'
```

I would guess the following implementation, but it displays:

```
    'Size:                      [] x [] pixels'
```

What is wrong ?

```
    <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Size:" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/desired_width"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="x" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/desired_height"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="pixels" />
</TableRow>
```

I'm under 100 reputation and cannot answer my own question, but zapl is right, it's a problem oh behavior between TableRow and LinearLayout:

The solution if to create a LinearLayout inside the TableRow:

```
 <TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Size:" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/desired_width"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="x" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/desired_height"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="pixels" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Since TableRow extends LinearLayout, is it a bug in the android sdk !?

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_weight` works for LinearLayout only.

Something like this might work for you:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1,3" >
```

that should grow columns 1 and 3 (starting at 0)

Comment: It's indeed a problem on my example ! But it do not solve the proble inside the table row :(

Comment: But there was the same kind of problem on the TableRow: it do not behave like a LinearLayout, I had to nest a LinearLayout in it to have the correct layout.