# Layout Weights do not work inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to assign layout weights to several items within a `LinearLayout` inside of a `ScrollView`. However, the `ScrollView` ignores the `LinearLayout` `weightSum`.

My goal is to divide the layout with weights of 2, 1, 1 (for a total sum of 4), but this does not work properly inside of a `ScrollView`.

How can I solve this layout problem?

**main.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/logo1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000" />


        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/logobutton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:background="#4B4B4B" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: check this one : [Android Layout Weight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986861/android-layout-weight) I think it kind of the same problem.

Comment: if i am removing only scrollview than is work but  my question is if am use scrollview than is not work

Answer (score 169, accepted):

I have faced this problem before. Just use `android:fillViewport="true"` in your ScrollView and it will fill up the screen.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
```

Comment: @MIPTECH : try this answer. More info at romain guy's http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/

Comment: Thanks man, I was really looking for a solution and it is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Works well in portrait, but not is a solution good in horitzontal, not work correctly

Comment: Best Solution. Was really helpful.

Answer (score 3):

This won't work as you have done it. The child view of a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) should be set to `wrap_content`. If you set it to `fill_parent`, it will fill the area of the [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) and never scroll, because it won't be larger than the [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

The idea of `layout_weight` is to fill a specific area proportionately.

You should set all of the child [LinearLayouts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) `layout_height` to either `wrap_content` or a specific size (in dp) and the parent [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) `layout_height` to `wrap_content`

As said you need to remove the additional

> xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

if it's not the root (first) element of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

just put this in your scroll view:

`android:fillViewport="true"`

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, `fillviewport=true` works bit strange.

I solved this problem by wrapping `LinearLayout` with another Layout like `FrameLayout`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Andy. Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for your answer. But this answer is very thin on details. You should show a sample that demonstrates the wrapping that you mention. See these [Tips for answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add below line in your ScrollView it will be work fine.

**Only single child must be there for ScrollView**

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```