# layout_weight is not working inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview

I can't figure out , why layout_weight is not working inside the ScrollView , when i am running this xml , i am getting imageview capturing the whole screen and below that i can see my tabs and the viewpager got hidden .

When i am giving the height in dp to all the linear layout below the ScrollView , i am getting my view perfectly ,why it's happening . i want my imageview to take 30% screen and tab/viewpager to take 70% of screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.emilsjolander.components.StickyScrollViewItems.StickyScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="10">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:background="@color/gift_vouchr_header_img"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_gift"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/splash"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager_ll"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/lvb_divider_color"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:tag="sticky"
                    android:layout_weight="7"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    >
                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/common_tablayout"
                        style="@style/VoucherTabLayoutStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_48">
                    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/common_viewpager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
    </com.emilsjolander.components.StickyScrollViewItems.StickyScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

When i remove weightsum and hardcoding the height then the view is working perfectly : below is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.emilsjolander.components.StickyScrollViewItems.StickyScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="160dp"
                    android:background="@color/gift_vouchr_header_img"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageview_gift"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/splash"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/viewpager_ll"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/lvb_divider_color"
                    android:layout_height="500dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:tag="sticky"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center">

                    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                        android:id="@+id/common_tablayout"
                        style="@style/VoucherTabLayoutStyle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        app:tabGravity="fill"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_48">
                    </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


                    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/common_viewpager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
    </com.emilsjolander.components.StickyScrollViewItems.StickyScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MyTab1 xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">



    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/gift_amount_footer_txt"
        android:text="@string/validity"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/voucher_common_layout"/>

    </LinearLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/gift_title_txt"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_26"
            android:text="@string/receiver_detail"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/receiver_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_48"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/QuaternaryTextColor"
            android:hint="@string/receiver_name"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_2"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_23"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/receiver_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_48"
            android:hint="@string/receiver_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/QuaternaryTextColor"

            style="@style/giftEditetxtStyle"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_2"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_30"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/receiver_mobile"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_48"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/QuaternaryTextColor"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:hint="@string/receiver_mobile"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/margin_2"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_30"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_40"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_30"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_12"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/send_cb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/gift_term_condition"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                android:text="@string/gift_terms_condition"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_send_gift"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/gift_submit_btn"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_20"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

MyTab2 xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_15"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_15">

    <include layout="@layout/voucher_common_layout"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/terms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_40"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_12"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/buy_cb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/gift_term_condition"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_5"
                android:text="@string/gift_terms_condition"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/gift_buy_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/gift_submit_btn"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_30"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: I guess you want that "Submit" Button near the bottom of the page, close to the navigation. if that is the case, you should write it as last sentence. My guess is that you should use a different type of layout, but I'm just guessing here.

Comment: what do you want? your button will be shown below.

Comment: yes i need submit button at the last , but i had put that button in the fragment , i don't need that button in the main layout , because the two tab has different type of button in shape and size, it's buttom of the layout itself , but when i scroll it keeps on scrolling and leaving extra space

Comment: @farhana there is two tab each tab is having it's own layout , in each layout there is view which contains button at the end , the layout is perfect but when i am scrolling upward then the button goes up , what i need when user scroll then it's show only same height but it's showing me extra height , i am putting my xml in code for the view

Comment: keep your button outside the `ScrollView` and take another view outside ScrollView` which will place both the view at their position then your button will not scroll with the content.

Comment: @AmitRanjan give the parent linear layout containing checkbox and textview weight=1.

Comment: @AmanRawat , I did but still it's not working , i edited my code aswell as description

Comment: @AmitRanjan what i meant above was to do your changes in your fragment also make your view pagers height match_parent .

Comment: @AmanRawat i change my tab fragment to match parent it's height but still not working ,updated the code above .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Layout Weights do not work inside a ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312272/layout-weights-do-not-work-inside-a-scrollview)

Answer (score 0):

None of the above solution worked for me , i found the solution myself like this : hope it will help someone : No changes in the tab code . In the main xml , i have done like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.emilsjolander.components.StickyScrollViewItems.StickyScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/childImg_rl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/gift_vouchr_header_img"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageview_gift"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/splash"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/viewpager_ll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/lvb_divider_color"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:tag="sticky"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center">

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/common_tablayout"
                    style="@style/VoucherTabLayoutStyle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:tabGravity="fill"
                    app:tabMode="fixed"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/margin_48">
                </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>


                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/common_viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </com.emilsjolander.components.StickyScrollViewItems.StickyScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here comes the important part : Pragmatically set the height of the child layout :D

```
private void setViewPagerandImageViewHeight(){
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        int heightOfScreen = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
        child_img_ll.getLayoutParams().height= (int) (heightOfScreen*.30);// set imageview linearlayout to capture 30% of screen
        viewpager_ll.getLayoutParams().height=heightOfScreen;//while scrolling set the viewpager height to maximum ,intially it capture 70% of screen

    }
```