# ScrollView and layout_weight="1"?

Tags: android, scrollview

I have ads layout under the `ScrollView`. In order to prevent the `ScrollView` overlapping ads layout, I have to use

```
<ScrollView 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" //          <--- THIS!
            >
                //...scrollview content
</ScrollView>

<include layout="@layout/ads_468x60"/>
```

What is the meaning of `layout_weight` if both width and height have been set to `fill_parent`?

According to documentation, this should not work, or to be precise, if both `layout_height` and `layout_width` have been set other than `0dp`, then `layout_weight` is disregarded. But, in this example it works and bottom ads layout will not be shown without the attribute `android:layout_weight="1"` inside of the `ScrollView`.

Comment: why don't you use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` of RelativeLayout to place Ads at bottom of screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use android:layout_height="0dp"

android:layout_weight="1" tells layout manager to fill all the free space.

Comment: You did not get. Even if I set this way, **the bottom ads layout IS visible** although it should not have been. Why is it still visible? Please try it yourself. The parent is LayoutView

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what are you trying to achieve. You want to have scrollView that holds all free space in layout and some view(ads) in the bottom or what?

Comment: Yes. And I know how to do it. I do not understand why the upper code works when I haven't set layout_height to 0dp.

Comment: because no matter what you set to android:layout_height, it is ignored so that layout_weight has higher priority. For example Eclipse give you an advice while creating xml that you SHOULD but not NEED to you use 0dp when setting  android:layout_weight="1". You can explore ViewGroup sources...I suppose in onMeasure or in onLayout methods you find what you're interested about.

Comment: Upvote for mentioning priorities. It's a valuable info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the layout_weight makes it ok to make your view *smaller* than defined (fill_parent) and it is shrinked to fit the screen space available. The weight indicates how to change the sizes of one or more components relatively to each other. In your case, you have just one view with weight. It is considered faster to use 0dp, as the system needs to measure less.

Comment: Do you mean "you have one view with **set layout_width** parameter?

Answer (score 0):

layout_weight is used for situations when you want to decide dynamically the width or height, so when you say layout_height = "0dp". 
It actually now depends on layout_weight attribute to make correct decision for it.
So by setting up weightsum property on parent layout you can accordingly distribute weights on child layouts by providing layout_weight.

refer this guy's answer and description on layout_weight :
[Android Layout Weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986861/android-layout-weight?lq=1)