# TextView pushing right-placed controls out of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to put a TextView on the left-side and a control (eg. a CheckBox) on the right of the TextView. I want the control to be left-aligned on the screen. This is not hard to obtain through a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout. For example I did this with LinearLayout:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/todo_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
         android:maxLines="2"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/todo_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="false"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that when the TextView's text is too long, it pushes the checkbox out of the screen and the checkbox is no longer visible. Instead, I want that the checkbox is fixed at the right-end of the screen and the TextView eventually split in two lines if necessary.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you  tried playing with `layout_weight` and `weightsum` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `android:layout_weight="1"` for textview and checkbox will always be on right side. Check this: [Android Layout Weight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986861/android-layout-weight)

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/todo_title"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
      android:maxLines="2"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:textStyle="bold" />
  <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/todo_checkbox"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:enabled="false"
      android:focusable="false"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `weightsum` and `layout_weight`.

Weightsum is a value given to a parent, saying all children components have to add up to the sum.

Layout_weight is given to the children of that layout. The value corresponds to the amount of the layout the component will occupy.

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightsum = "100" >
   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/todo_title"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
      android:maxLines="2"
      android:layout_weight="30"
      android:textStyle="bold" />
  <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/todo_checkbox"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:enabled="false"
      android:layout_weight="70"
      android:focusable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Keep in mind that the values are reversed (not sure how it works), but the largest layout_weight value occupies the smallest area.

Comment: Play around with the values of layout_weight. Does it yield the same result for all values?