# Few questions about android's screen orientation

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I write a rectangle widget.

After writing its portrait XML, I want to write its landscape.

1. I should change any `LinearLayout` orientation from horizontal to
   vertical?

   horizontal is right to left (not top to bottom) relative to the
   screen in origin portrait mode?
2. If i don't mention `layout_height` property, what is the default?
   (`match parent?`)
3. how does `weight` property take effect when I specify
   `layout_width = X dip`?

   when I specify `layout_width = wrap_content`?
4. what does `fill_parent` mean when in top-most `LinearLayout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1a) No, you should not.

1b) Horizontal is left to right relative to the screen in origin portrait mode.

2) There is no default value, you have to set it (other time you will see an error)

3) Please look at [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986861/android-layout-weight)

4) The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding)

Comment: 4) but this is the top-most. who is its parent? the whole screen size?

Comment: but if (1b) is true, then (1a) is not logic. If horizontal stays relative to portrait mode, then I now have to change every orientation to vertical mode. it not- please explain.

Comment: @EladBenda Ad 4 - yes, it will be as the screen size

Comment: Thanks, how about my first comment?

Comment: that's weird, I have copy pasted my portrait xml to landscape (leaving linear-layout orientation as is) and it all looked fine. It doesn't settled with (1a) + (1b) in my question

Answer (score 0):

To give the task of managing screen orientation to Android on behalf, you don't need to think all this stuff. Just mention `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout"` in your activity from AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: `Note: Using this attribute should be avoided and used only as a last resort. `