# how to set scaleble (weighted) space between linearlayout children?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, layout

I want to create a gap between two children of linearLayout.

I don't want to use margin or padding, as this will not scale properly

when I switch to landscape.

I prefer using weight. But then, how to create a dummy (gap only) view in between them?

by the way, what happens if I don't create a landscape xml and

change the device orientation from portrait to landscape?

**UPDATE 1**

I have tried:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_information"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.47"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_destination"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="\@ Home in"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/solid_white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

but then

I get warning about nested weighting performance.

I get runtime error when drawing my gadget

Comment: Try replacing your "wrap_content" height with 0dp.. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building for ICS and above, use a `Space` widget :

```
<Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="YourWeight"/>
```

(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Space.html)

Otherwise, you could just use an empty `View`.

You might also consider if using a `RelativeLayout` would be more efficient in your case.

When the device is rotated and you don't have a dedicated layout for landscape, your portrait will be used.

Comment: why `RelativeLayout` be more efficient? I still have to create empty view

Comment: You would not have to create empty views if there are other `Views` you could use as anchors for your `Views`. However, I don't know your exact layout structure, so this was just a suggestion.

Comment: I think `match_parent` conflicts with `weight` property

Comment: As long as all your other views have a `weight`, `match_parent` or `fill_parent` and `weight` won't conflict.

Comment: see the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986861/android-layout-weight

Comment: The case in this question is different than yours: The OP wanted the `TextView` to only be as wide as its content (`wrap_content`), while you want the gap `View` to fill all the remaining space.

Comment: I dont get it. `while you want the gap View to fill all the remaining space.` then why do  need weight at all? it fill all the remaining. This is not what i have asked.

Comment: Btw, I was wrong above, `match_parent` and `weight` even work together if only this one `View` has a `weight`, but the `weight` value will be ignored.

Comment: With fill_parent only, the gap view would push all following widgets out of the screen. With a weight value, the gap view will just fill the otherwise empty space, leaving enough space for all following widgets.