# Android percentage (weight) is not giving expected results

Tags: c#, android, xaml, percentage

I am designing an Android interface and I discovered I can give percentage to the control as `Weight`.

But when I use the following code :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="310.1dp"
    android:layout_weight=".70"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:background="#C49268">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".30"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
```

The first layout is taking 70% of the page : `android:layout_weight=".70"`

The second layout is taking 30% of the page : `android:layout_weight=".30"` and a bottom gravity. So it should use the whole page. (100%).

What I understand from this is that the RelativeLayout should take 30% of the bottom space and the LinearLayout should take 70% of the top space for a total of 100% of the screen.

When I boot the app, I still see a black bar at the bottom (unused space). Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4986861/android-layout-weight

Answer (score 2):

The main thing to keep in mind about `layout_weight` is that it distributes the REMAINING space.  So, you should be setting whichever dimension (height or width) to "0dp" if you want to distribute things correctly.

In your case, you should be setting the `layout_height` to `0dp` for both of your layouts

Comment: I missed the part where it is attributing remaining space. So I could set everything to 0dp and wack percentages everywhere?

Comment: Ah, found it.  Here is the page that explained it really well for me. It demonstrates the differences between setting to 0dp and not.  You'll want to set both `android:layout_weight` and `android:layout_height=0dp` for your `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` [link](http://rlaenen.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-layoutweight-attribute-how-to.html)

Comment: My bad, this is the correct one I was searching for (had bookmarked both). It's google cached since the page seems to be down now :( [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:1iXetZu-4WsJ:ugiagonzalez.com/2012/01/19/android-linearlayout-distribution-explained-weight-and-sizes/+&cd=8&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

Answer (score 0):

try changing layout height to `0dp` for both layouts and it should work

Comment: Thanks ! Is this bad practice (like a workaround) or is it good to do ?

Answer (score -2):

change `layout_width="fill_parent"`  and give it a background color. That will fix your problem.

Comment: On which layout ? Also is this a solution or a workaround to fix something I don't quite understand ?